# How to target input box that's not in html form - PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to PHP, so my entire perspective of how I should build something like this might be wrong, so please give tips as needed!

Pretty much the app should push data to the db when submit is clicked. I handle that with a form in the html and this code in PHP (let's ignore injection hacking for now...)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
        $book = $_POST['book-num'];
...
```

The submit button is in a form like such

```
<div class="submission-field">
    <form method="post"><input class="submit-report" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is how to target the numerical input box (book-num) if it's not in a form? My input box and submission button aren't anywhere near eachother so I couldn't wrap it with the same `<form>` tag the submit button is in. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use js can help you:

```js
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="book-num" id="book-num">
</form>
...........
<input type="text" name="book-num-input" onchange="fillIn('book-num',this)">
  
<script>
  function fillIn(input_id,input){
    document.getElementById(input_id).value = input.value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That works! I'm wondering if there's any other clean ways to do this without an extra hidden html input.